# I want a randomly selected image using a javascript function to appear in a span in a separate part of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm working with the below function and want to use the image chosen from an array in a span (class of 'you') in the div that will appear after the temp one I create times out. Basically the end goal is each time someone loads the page they will have the prompt but get a different image, but they then have that image assigned to them for the rest of the game/until they leave or start over. So far I have been unsuccessful.

```
function characterSelect() {
  // prompt("Type your characteristics and our advanced AI will create an exact image of your face.") ;
  // Show prompt box to get user's input
  prompt("Type up to 10 of your physical characteristics and our advanced AI will create an exact image of you.");

  // Create a new div element
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const divId = 'random-image-div-' + Date.now(); // Generate a unique ID using the current timestamp
  div.setAttribute('id', divId);

  // Set the text content of the div to the user's input
  div.textContent = "Your exact replica is:";
  div.style.fontSize = "50px"; // Set font size to 20 pixels
  div.style.fontFamily = "Lucida Sans Unicode, sans-serif";
  div.style.fontWeight = "bold";

  // Generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

  // Create a new img element
  const img = document.createElement('img');

  // Set the src attribute of the img element to the randomly selected image URL
  img.src = images[randomIndex];

  // Append the img element to the div element
  div.appendChild(img);

  // Add the div element to the body of the HTML document
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  // Use setTimeout() function to wait for 3 seconds and then remove the div element
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    document.getElementById("theGame").style.display = 'block';
  }, 3000);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 3500);
})
```

I'm quite new to this and got the above code from various sources. Originally I wanted to create a variable within the function then just use it again outside of it but it looks like I can't do that.

I've tried to use `document.getElementById('you').innerHTML = \``;"`  as suggested by chatgpt but for some reason it didn't work and made nothing load in the random-image-div the function creates.

I'm wondering if there are any tricks I don't know about that I can use to make the span mirror the image used in the random-image-div? Seems like something that should be quite simple but I have been stuck on this for a couple of days.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: what is with the random escaping?

Comment: Well what is the error when you do it the other way>?

Comment: @epascarello That comes from the Stacks editor.

Comment: `document.getElementById('you').appendChild(div)`